# NSURLConnectionLoader(7):EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having a problem with `Webview` where i'm trying load the webpage in it. But everytime  my `ViewControler` loads I get the following crash

[image]

WebPage view : -

[image]

This is what I have done in my `viewDidLoad:` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _webView.delegate=self;
    _activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSString *headLinesNewsLink = _detailedWebLinkView.headlineLink;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:headLinesNewsLink];
    NSLog(@"URL is : %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *requestDetails = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    if(requestDetails)
    {
        [_webView loadRequest:requestDetails];
    }
}
```

I checked the same URL on safari and it gives me intended page.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to encode the the string while creating NSURL, if there are any special char in url they will be encoded.

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[headLinesNewsLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` added worked fine for few times but crashed at last.